# How to find port of a network scanner for UFW

Tags: firewall, scanner, ufw

Samsung multi-functional device SXC 3205w works perfectly with my Ubuntu 12.04 and I can scan and print over network, but only when firewall is disabled.

How can I find out which port to enable in UFW to make this printer work and have my firewall enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use fallowing command to trace communication between `pc` and `printer`

```
sudo tcpdump -i interface | grep ip_address_of_printer
```

You will see output of network communication, protocol, port ...

After that you can set `ufw`

Another way is to use command

```
netstat -atu | grep ip_address_of_printer
```

With this command you will see active connection between `pc` and `printer`.

Also you can allow all trafic for `printer` ip address

```
sudo ufw allow from ip_address_of_printer
```

Comment: After reboot, port of the device changed, so tcpdump and netstat is a short term solution, but it works, allowing an ip address looks more long term.

Comment: Thanks! That last command got mine to work.  Didn't know about that option in `ufw`