# How to configure ufw to allow xsane to reach scanner?

Tags: ufw, xsane

I could not find any clear answer through prior research.

Xsane fails to find the scanner with ufw enabled, works great with ufw off.

I have opened 6566 for both tcp and udp in ufw.  Still no joy.  I could not tell from watching the "listening report" in ufw which ports sane is using other than 6566.

If the ports are not standard but vary by scanner (this is a Canon) advice on how to locate the required ports would be most welcome.

Edit: I tried `sudo ufw allow saned` but I think this just opens port 6566 because the response back from the command was to the effect that it was already open.

Additional information: the port(s) that are being blocked seem to be related to scanner discovery and job status.  If I disable the firewall and start xsane, then turn on the firewall and scan, a scan will take place, but it repeats over and over (apparently a job completion status is not being sent).

`sudo netstat -lntp | grep saned` showed port 6566 but no others.  Perhaps the discovery/statuses are being sent too fast for me to see.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find port of a network scanner for UFW](http://askubuntu.com/questions/656800/how-to-find-port-of-a-network-scanner-for-ufw)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since my printer has a fixed IP address on the LAN, I was able to fix this by using the command

`sudo ufw allow from <ip address>`

Answer (score 3):

I would use `sudo netstat -lntp | grep saned` to check.

But sane has a pre-defined application profile: `sudo ufw allow saned`  should be all you need.

(`xsane` is the gui for `sane`)

Comment: This command produces no output for me, running an HP scanner on 15.10

Comment: That means sane is not running @CharlesGreen

Comment: Now I gotta go figure how my computer is talking to my scanner!

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately this did not work, but while trying it I learned some things I am adding to the question.

Comment: sigh, it's a duplicate question anyway.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reach my HP ENVY network attached scanner with (envy is device hostname):

```
$ xsane $(hp-makeuri envy 2>&1 | grep SANE | cut -d: -f2-)
```

No nf_conntrack_sane or special firewall configuration required:

```
# ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Anywhere/igmp              ALLOW       Anywhere/igmp             
32400                      ALLOW       192.168.1.0/24            
53                         ALLOW       192.168.1.0/24            
Samba                      ALLOW       192.168.1.0/24            
68/udp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
67/udp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
32400                      ALLOW       xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64   
53                         ALLOW       xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64   
Samba (v6)                 ALLOW       xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64   
68/udp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
67/udp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```